# How to wait for multiple interfaces to return in anular(rxjs)?

Tags: angular, rxjs

When I use Angualr's `HttpClient`(rxjs) request , I need to wait for multiple interfaces to return before rendering the page. What should I do? Similar to `Promise.all`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get each httpClient.get call as an observable, then all of them will have completed when `forkJoin(o1$, o2$, o3$)` emits a three-element array of their respective responses.

Comment: doc: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin